# How to get list of RecordIDs and bind to Guid list in LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

List documentIds = new List();
//TODO: get list of Document_RecordIDs from new intersect table

I need to populate list of Ids  and pass to

foreach (var documentId in documentIds)

Comment: List<Guid> documentIds = new List<Guid>();

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the Guid from Document_RecordIDs  and set it into the new created List<Guid> documentIds?